# Import Gdal not working

Tags: python, gdal

I used  `conda install -c conda-forge gal` to install the GDAL package. However, I got a following error in importing the package.

```
>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gdal.py", line 2, in 
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in 
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/name/anaconda/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried the followings but they didn't work for me:

`conda upgrade numpy`

`conda install libpng`

Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

I use anaconda as well and have also had issues installing GDAL in the past. Instead I usually download a wheel [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and do `pip install <file_name>.whl` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try "from osgeo import gdal", hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I think you could do either of the following to make GDAL work:

1) Install the latest version of OSGeo4W and install same version of python as explained in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/114674).

2) Download a free version of Enthought canopy from [here](https://store.enthought.com/downloads/). Make sure you download the appropriate version based on your platform. Then using their package manager, search for "gdal" in the search bar. Install the gdal package. Then you can either use the canopy IDE or use this python environment with any other python IDE like Wing (my favourite) by giving the python path of enthought canopy. You can install as many packages as you want from the package manager which are available. For the unavailable ones, you can use the canopy command prompt which is configured with pip.

I personally prefer the 2nd way.